# Mails deleted from Thunderbird while system formatting

Tags: windows-7, email, data-recovery, thunderbird

I am screwed and really disturbed. Since 1 year I am using Thunderbird in Windows 7 and receiving and sending emails using it. I have a GoDaddy hosted webmail account.

Now today I reinstalled Windows in my system and took backup of everything except Thunderbird and my mails are not available on My GoDaddy web-based email account also.

Is there any chance that I can get those emails back. As it is very important for me.

Comment: IIRC PhotoRec can search for deleted files. You can scan for email files.

Comment: @siebz0r Is it a software, i googled it but no result.

Comment: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: Was your account configured as POP with the option of keeping mails in the server disabled? Can't you get a backup or restore from godaddy?

Comment: No it was IMAP... and i am unable to recover it from Godaddy guyz.... maybe because all those emails were saved on my local system only :(

Answer (score 0):

You can only recover deleted files if they haven't been overwritten by other data. As you said you re-installed your system, chances are your email is gone. PhotoRec is an excellent piece of software that can recover a lot of files including Thunderbird's mbox format.

If you cannot recover the deleted mbox files and the email is very important, you can try and ask your email provider nicely to recover your email (chances are they'll just say no, but it's worth a shot).